# Changing Managed Metadata field

Tags: document-library, managed-metadata, term-store

Sorry if my syntax is a bit off here, I'm very new to Sharepoint.

We have a document library in Sharepoint with a Managed Metadata column for the department (we have a list of departments in the Term Store library). The organisation has restructured recently, and we need to change the Department column to reflect the new department names. Each of the old department names does map to a new department name, but its not a 1:1 thing (for eg OldDept1 and OldDept2 may now both be NewDept1), so we need to do some kind of mapping procedure.

What would be the best way to go about this? We thought about adding a calculated column with a formula to do the mapping, but that won't stand up for future additions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I would recommend you to add the new department names to the manage metadata store and merge the old departments with the new values. You shoul check out the following blog post http://term-management.com/2012/10/11/merging-terms-in-the-sharepoint-2010-term-store-2/